# search for the first character entered happens when the 2nd character is also entered. How do I fix this?

Tags: android, kotlin, search, android-listview, listadapter

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYXCi.png)

this is a searchview's onQueryTextChange. I'm applying a filter to an adapter and setting a listview's adapter to the filtered adapter. If the filtered adapter.count is not 0, it should make a view visible, else gone.

The problem starts when I type a letter in the searchview. The value of adapter.count is length of the list when 1 character is entered in the searchview. When I enter the 2nd character, adapter.count changes to the number of items matching the 1st character entered if there's a match, or turns 0. I want the value of adapter.count to be length of the list before I type anything and the 1st character filter should be applied when the first character is typed.

TL;DR: search for the first character entered happens when the 2nd character is also entered. How do I fix this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but arrayAdapterFavourites is a list that you pass to your adapter or the adapter itself? It's an adapter, right?

Avoid setting the adapter of your recyclerView dynamically. Set it at onCreate instead, for example.

After you filter the list you passed to your adapter with the query you typed on your search view, you must to update the adapter's list and notify your adapter that its content has changed in order to see the result, using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for example or any other variation. (Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) to understand the difference between them)

Moreover, I recommend using `if (list.isNotEmpty)` instead of `if (adapter.count != 0)`.

I hope that can help you.